# Vertically centering text inside flexbox item

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I want the flex items to take full height, but the content inside them to be vertically centred.

`justify-content: centre` doesn't work, and `align-self: centre` on the item itself shrinks its height to its own content, while I want all items to be the same height.

In this example I want the numbers to be vertically centred: http://codepen.io/ilyador/pen/ogYbWO?editors=110

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;  
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1fbdms s s sdj dfkg kjfg dkfj gdfjkgdfkj gdfkjg dfkjgdkhdfjk gkjdfkjdfgdfg jkdfgdfjkgk </li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just wondering...why do you need the items to have 100% height?

Comment: I need all the items to be the same height as the tallest one

Comment: *Why* do you need them to be the same height as the tallest? You want to *center* them - don't you?

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Comment: Something like this: http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/ByQjJL

Comment: Thanx but no, I need each to have it's own background.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was asking all along.... you need the items to take 100% height because each on e has their own background.

Comment: You need to use nested flexboxes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32828900/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B that is what I was hoping to avoid but apparently could not... Table-cells are much easier in this way

Comment: @Andrey, nesting flex containers is not really a big deal. And you keep the ability to use flex properties, which provides more flexibility than tables.

Comment: @Michael_B oh, seems I was wrong — you just need ```display: flex``` on inner elements to center their content, but inside them you do not need to add extra inner wrapper element with ```display: flex``` just to make a centering, as I originally thought. In other words — you always have an element to put ```display: flex``` on

Comment: @Andrey, you are correct. You do not need to add a wrapper to content because CSS automatically creates [*anonymous boxes*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items). For more details about centering *the content of a flex item* see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276). Cheers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to accomplish vertical centering of your numbers with this:

```
.flex-item {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

If you want something to be vertically centered, set the container to `display:flex` and then use `justify-content` to accomplish it. With `justify-content` you could either set it to `space-around` or to `center`. Either will accomplish your goal.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoajg

Comment: This is a good answer. Just a note this will not work for IE 10 and lower.

Comment: @serverjohn _flexbox_ doesn't work in IE10 or lower. so... I'm fine with that. http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: so so good! thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Give the flex items `display: flex` and `align-items: center`. The flex items contents will now be vertically centered.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
body > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #F00;
}
body > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F90;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>is</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>vertically</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>centered</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct response.